# Issues with Progressbar in Delphi

Tags: delphi

i have a program that am working on that increments the progressbar by a certain value after a number of executions.
the problem is the progressbar is not updated correctly but viewing the value passed to the progressbar through the debugger indicates that the incrementing value is passed correctly.
Progressbar max value is set to 100.

Here is my Snippet

```
 function ParseasArray(Const sInput: String): TMyArray;

var
  iCount, iIncrement, iSizeofArray, iStepper, iPercenter, iTester,
    iHolder: Integer;

  dDoubleCalcVal: Double;

begin
  iIncrement := 1;
  iPercenter := 10;
  iHolder := 1;

  iSizeofArray := Trunc(Length(sInput) / 2);
  SetLength(result, iSizeofArray);
  for iCount := 1 to iSizeofArray do
  begin
    // do some work
    dDoubleCalcVal := (((iCount) / iSizeofArray));
    iStepper := Trunc(dDoubleCalcVal * 100);

    iTester := Trunc((iPercenter * iSizeofArray) / 100);

    if iCount = iTester then
    begin
      Form1.Indicator.Position := iStepper;
      inc(iPercenter, 10);
    end;

    inc(iIncrement, 2);
  end;

end;
```

My IDE Version

Delphi XE7 Update 1

Thanks.

Comment: This is expected. Of course your thread cannot update its GUI, when it is busy executing your loop!

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong. What is the problem?

Comment: yes but the funny thing is that if i do this    

  if (iCount) mod (2) = 0 then
        begin
        Form1.Indicator.Position := iStepper;
        end;

instead of this

if iCount = iTester then
    begin
      Form1.Indicator.Position := iStepper;
      inc(iPercenter, 10);
    end;
it works fine.

Comment: @ David, the progressbar is not updated correctly as per the proper number of times it is meant to.

Comment: Can't you tell us what the problem is? I've no idea yet what you mean. Please say more than "not updated correctly". Describe what should happen, and what does happen.

Comment: @ david, as per my code above, the progressbar is meant to be updated 10 times but it gets updated just twice at random positions.

Comment: FWIW you can and should avoid floating point calcs. The arithmetic can all be done using integer ops.

Comment: As Andreas said, you cannot expect the UI to respond when it's busy in a loop. And as David says, you need to be a lot more specific. This needs to be in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Just add Indicator.Refresh to verify..